# Convert sql query with LEFT join into lambda or Linq expression

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have below `SQL` query and I want it to convert into either `Lambda` or `Linq` expression for `C#`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT employeeid
INTO #temp
FROM [dbo].DOCS
WHERE companyid = 1
    AND taxyear = 2015

SELECT DISTINCT e.EmployeeId,
                e.EmployeeName
FROM Employees e
LEFT JOIN #temp t ON e.EmployeeId = t.employeeid
WHERE CompanyId = 1
ORDER BY EmployeeName
```

Comment: I want to filter first DOCS table and then want to left join with Employees table. Not getting it that how to do with Linq or Lambda expression

Comment: Google `Linqer` - sql to linq converter

Comment: Below expression I tried but that's giving wrong number of rows -

(from l in db.Employees join p in db.DOCS on l.EmployeeId equals p.EmployeeId

                                           into temp from j in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()

                              where l.CompanyId == cust.Id && j.CompanyId == cust.Id && j.TaxYear == taxYear

                              select new { l.EmployeeId, l.EmployeeName }).Distinct().OrderBy(X => X.EmployeeName).ToList();

Comment: I don't have converter on my machine and can not install it due to admin restriction... Can anyone do it for me?

Comment: Are you getting too few or too many rows.  I think you need a left outer join which include A join B where the join field is null in A.  See webpage : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 0):

it's resolved and I got below solution -

```
var result = 
(from l in db.Employees 
 join p in db.docs.Where(j => j.CompanyId == 1 && j.TaxYear == 2015) 
 on l.EmployeeId equals p.EmployeeId into temp    
 where l.CompanyId == 1
    select new 
      { EmployeeId =  l.EmployeeId, 
        EmployeeName = l.EmployeeName 
 }).Distinct().OrderBy(X => X.EmployeeName).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ViewSapIqosGdpF8
    .Where(x=>x.Claim.TblFieldClaimsHarmonized)
    .Any(y=>y.Vclaim.ViewFieldClaimsHarmonized)
    .Select(x=>x)
```

Where Claim and Vclaim are References of Foreign Keys